# Custom defined ports for hadoop components

Tags: hadoop

I was wondering if we can define ports ourself for hadoop components to use. There are defaults ports hadoop components use , like for web hadoop port is 50070, so can we configure it to use port 50000. Likewise can we tell hadoop components ( Spark, hive etc) to use own defined ports?

Will it be okay if I opened ports from 9000 to 9500 only and block other ports and configure hadoop to use port between that range ?

Comment: Yeah, why not? But you will have to update each and every `hdfs-site.xml`, `yarn-site.xml` etc. etc. on each and every node, the private versions (used by services) and public versions (in `/etc/*/conf`), and also the versions used by remote clients. And make sure you don't revert to the defaults on upgrade. Lots of fun. Happy debugging!

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I know the risks but my office wants to use virtual server and was asking me to list all ports I will be using. This is somewhat ridiculous question as I cannot list all the ports. So I was planning to give them a range and i will configure ports between that range

Comment: Well, once you have a Hadoop cluster up and running, you *can* list the ports waiting for inbound connections -- cf. `sudo ss --listening -p` on every node. Note that HTTP ports will change if you switch to HTTPS or vice-versa.